# stickybits setgid not working

Tags: debian, group, setgid, sticky-bit

I have structure like:

```
/home/reed/, user=reed, group=reed
  - apache-conf, user=reed, group=reed
  - apache-web, user=reed, group=apache, perm=0770
      - www.website.com, user=reed, group=apache, perm=0770
          - index.php, user=reed, group=apache, perm=0660
```

I'm using `umask 007` in `/etc/profile` so my directories & files are created with these same permissions. & that worked.

I ran `chmod g+s /home/reed/apache-web;` and `chmod g+s /home/reed/apache-web/www.website.com` so new directories will keep the `group=apache`

So I `mkdir /home/reed/apache-web/test/`, then `ls -la ...` & it shows `reed` is both the user & the group.

I tried using `chmod 4770 /home/reed/apache-web/test/`, but `mkdir` still sets both user & group to `reed` (or `root` if I'm running with sudo)

I tried it in the `www.website.com` dir as well with the same results.

I'm on Debian 10 with root access available. I also tried switching to user=apache & group=reed, then using `chmod u+s thedir`, but again, `mkdir` makes both the user & the group the current shell user. I also tried logging out & logging back in

Comment: Please check if the setgid flag is really set on the directories. `chmod g+s thedir` doesn't seem to have an effect (without `sudo`) on my system if my current user doesn't belong to the directories' group.

Comment: I thought I had done that! That appears to have fixed it :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have /home mounted with the `nosuid` option:

> ```
>    nosuid Do not allow set-user-identifier or set-group-identifier bits to
>           take effect.
> ```

Comment: My `/etc/fstab` file has `UUID=[the_uuid] / ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1`. I'm assuming I would see here `nosuid` if that were the case?

Comment: Probably, but you wouldn't put a `nosuid` on /. Some distributions place it on `/home`, but generally that doesn't need setuid/setdid programs. Are you sure `/home` isn't on its own partition? What is the output of `mount` with no parameters?

Comment: Looks like `tmpfs on /run/user/#### type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=101368k,mode=700,uid=####,gid=####)` is the one I'm concerned with. It's cloud-hosting. I assume there's a config file somewhere that I can remove the `nosuid` param?

Comment: Running `sudo chmod g+s` made it start working. Though I'm now confused as to why `nosuid` isn't being respected...

Comment: No, `/run/user` is quite different from `/home`. as you mention `sudo chmod` made it work, it is possible that the kernel has a CONFIG_ parameter set to only allow setgid to succeed if done by root.